# How to format range of two LocalDate variables in Java?

Tags: java, formatter, localdate, datetimeformatter

I'm familiar with the DateTime Formatter in regards to applying LocalDate to a single variable, but don't know how to handle the following situation:
I've two LocalDate variables, for example startOfWeek and endOfWeek.
And I need to create String result with following rules:

1. if startOfWeek and endOfWeek have same month and year, the result should be like
   **3 - 9 Jan 2021** (just an example with format)
2. if startOfWeek and endOfWeek have not same month, the result should be like **31 Oct - 6 Nov 2021**
3. if startOfWeek and endOfWeek have not same year, the result should be like **27 Dec 2020 - 2 Jan 2021**

I didn't find how to apply DateTime Formatter working with two of more LocalDate variables, so I've made this way:

```
if ((startOfWeek.getYear() != endOfWeek.getYear())){
                result.append(startOfWeek.getDayOfMonth() + " " + startOfWeek.getMonth() + " " + startOfWeek.getYear() +
                        " - " + endOfWeek.getDayOfMonth() + " " + endOfWeek.getMonth() + " " + startOfWeek.getYear());
                return  result.toString();
            } else if ((startOfWeek.getMonth() != endOfWeek.getMonth())) {
                result.append(startOfWeek.getDayOfMonth() + " " + startOfWeek.getMonth() +
                        " - " + endOfWeek.getDayOfMonth() + " " + endOfWeek.getMonth() + " " + startOfWeek.getYear());
                return  result.toString();
            } else {
                result.append(startOfWeek.getDayOfMonth() +
                        " - " + endOfWeek.getDayOfMonth() + " " + startOfWeek.getMonth() + " " + startOfWeek.getYear());
                return  result.toString();
```

But it return information about months in default format, for example SEPTEMBER

[Full example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrtj6.png)

Does anybody now how to fix month data format or how to use DateTime Formatter with two LocalDate variables at one time?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a `DateTimeFormatter` to get a formated month string

```
DateTimeFormatter month  = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM");
```

In addition to that I would do the task with 3 `DateTimeFormatter`s and the `YearMonth` and `Year` classes from `java.time` API which could make your if else blocks a bit more readable:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Year;
import java.time.YearMonth;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.List;

....


static String formattedRange (LocalDate start, LocalDate end){
    DateTimeFormatter onlyDate      = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d");
    DateTimeFormatter dateAndMonth  = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMM");
    DateTimeFormatter dateMonthYear = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d MMM yyyy");

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    if (YearMonth.from(start).equals(YearMonth.from(end))){
        result.append(onlyDate.format(start)).append(" - ")
              .append(dateMonthYear.format(end));
    }
    else if (Year.from(start).equals(Year.from(end))){
        result.append(dateAndMonth.format(start)).append(" - ")
              .append(dateMonthYear.format(end));
    }
    else {
        result.append(dateMonthYear.format(start)).append(" - ")
              .append(dateMonthYear.format(end));
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would just use a [Formatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Formatter.html) string:

```
String format;
if (startOfWeek.getYear() != endOfWeek.getYear()) {
    format = "%te %<tb %<tY - %te %<tb %<tY";
} else if (startOfWeek.getMonth() != endOfWeek.getMonth()) {
    format = "%te %<tb - %te %<tb %<tY";
} else {
    format = "%te - %te %<tb %<tY";
}

return String.format(format, startOfWeek, endOfWeek);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.getDisplayName(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/spi/CalendarNameProvider.html#getDisplayName-java.lang.String-int-int-int-java.util.Locale-) method directly on the `getMonth()` method to get the desired localized month name format. In your case, here is an example code:

```
startOfWeek.getMonth().getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT_STANDALONE,Locale.getDefault())
endOfWeek.getMonth().getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT_STANDALONE, Locale.getDefault())
```